# Calculate Geometric Progression with logarithm

Tags: summation, logarithms, geometric-progressions

I'm trying to find the following summation but cant seem to find the answer. Would really appreciate any help from here!

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}(4/3)^{i}\log(n/3^i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(4/3)^i\log(n/3^i)=(4/3)^i(\log n-\log(3^i))=(4/3)^i(\log n-i\log 3)$$

So, your sum is,

$$\log n\left[\sum_{i=0}^k (4/3)^i\right]-\log 3\left[\sum_{i=0}^k i(4/3)^i\right]$$

The first summand has a finite geometric series and the second summand has a finite arithmetico-geometric series. Do you know how to compute them?

Comment: I understood what u did there but I think i cant compute them

Comment: @Khadar111: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms). Can you do it now?

Comment: I think i can do now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Khadar111: Glad to help! If you found this answer useful, you can accept it to mark your question as resolved.